# What is the sum function $s(x)$?

Tags: calculus

What is the sum function $s(x)$ of $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n-1}{2^n}x^{2n-2}$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

- What’s a closed form for

$$x\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)^n\;?$$

Now note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)^n\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^n}\right)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{2n+1}{2^n}x^{2n}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2n-1}{2^{n-1}}x^{2n-2}\;,$$

and do a little fiddling around.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Write the sum as

$$s(x)=x^{-2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x^2)^n-x^{-2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x^2/2)^n$$

Then sum the two geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{x^2}{2})^n$. Then we have $s(x)=f'(x)$.

Since $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$,  $s(x)=f'(x)=\frac{2-3x}{(2-x^2)^2}$.

The convergence radius is clearly $\sqrt{2}$. Check the boundary situation, i.e. when $x=\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}.$ It turns out both of make the summation diverge.